# How to quickly cd to a command's directory after used the 'which' or 'type'

Tags: bash, command-line

I want to cd to the directory of go's bin file:

```
$ type go  
go is /c/tools/go/bin/go
```

How can I quickly cd to this directory in bash ?

Comment: What do you mean by quickly? Like, a short command that brings you to the directory?

Comment: this is dupplicate, but @Jijin's answer looks better.

Comment: @SpecialBomb yes. this is what i expect. since I don't much about bash, so the answer is open, maybe there some keybord shortcut to let me do this kind of things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 cd $(dirname $(which go))
```

`which go` will show the path of the executable. Then get the `dirname` of that path and `cd` to that.

Comment: won't `which` return the path to the executable file? cd will never work if it is true

Comment: @lese `dirname` removes the file at the end by checking if it's a file, so it works.

Comment: What if there is no executable, shouldn't you handle the error...

Comment: `which go &&  cd $(dirname $(which go))` . Won't `cd` if first `which go` fails.